# ending my total with two zeros, i cant find anything on the internet that is clear to me

Tags: python-3.x

#Let's start a coffee shop together!! We're going to build a coffee shop using some new Python programming concepts!!

#Let's build robot Barista!!

```
from time import sleep

print("\nHello! Welcome to Star Bucks.")
name = input("What is your name?\n")
print("Hello " + name + ", thank you so much for coming in today.\n")

sleep(2)

#To make it wait two seconds before showing the menu

menu = "Black Coffee, Espresso, Latte, Cappucino"

print (name + ", what would you like from our menu today? Here is what we are serving.\n" + menu)

order = input()

price = float(2.50)

quantity = input("How many " + order + "'s would you like?\n")

total = price * float(quantity)

print(format("Thank you. Your total of " + quantity + " " + order + " will be €" + str(total)))

print("\nSounds good " + name + ", we'll have your " + quantity + " " + order + "'s ready for you in a moment.")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the float like this "{:.2f}".format(total)

Your last line becomes:

```
print(format("Thank you. Your total of " + quantity + " " + order + " will be €" + "{:.2f}".format(total)))
```